# Does a function with an exponential growth condition necessarily have infinitely many zeros?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

This is part (2) of a question that I am working on.

In part(1), I have constructed an entire function $f:=\cosh(\sqrt{z})$ that grows like

$$\lim_{r \to \infty} \frac {\log M(r)}{\sqrt{r}}=1$$

where M(r) = $\max\limits_{|z|=r} |f(z)|$.

Then equivalently, $\cosh(\sqrt{z})$ grows like $\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{r}}$.

The question is now:

**"Does every function $f(z)$ whose growth rate is given above have infinitely many zeros?  Give your reasons."**

My attempt:

First, we know that analyzing the behavior of such functions $f(z)$ at infinity is equivalent to analyzing $f(\frac{1}{z})$ as $z \to 0$.

Looking at the Laurent series, expanded about the origin, say for $\cosh(\sqrt{z})$, and inverting the argument, we get

$$\sum \frac{z^n}{(2n)!} \to \sum \frac{1}{z^n(2n)!}$$

Here's where I am a little confused.  Does this automatically mean that 0 is an essential singularity of $f(1/z)$, so that $\infty$ is an essential singularity for $f(z)$?  Just merely writing the series with an inverted argument makes all of the positive power z terms change into negative power terms - and infinitely many negative power terms about $z = 0$ implies, by definition, that $0$ is an essential singularity of $f(1/z)$.

But that seems silly, because then *every* function, written with the argument inverted, would suggest that it has an essential singularity at $0$, and therefore an essential singularity at $\infty$ for $f(z)$.  What is wrong with my thinking?

Moving on, I could then use Big Picard's theorem and argue that near the essential singularity, $f(z)$ picks up every complex value, with an exception of at most one value.  Then $f(z) = 0$ is fulfilled infinitely often, as we wanted to show.  But, what if $z=0$ were that exceptional point?  Then...how can I say anything at all about $f(z)$ attaining $0$...even once?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Does $e^{\sqrt{z}}$ have any zeros?

Comment: Ohh...of course not...hmm...thanks so much @MattSamuel.

Comment: Only problem is that isn't analytic. Need to be a little more clever than that, but I'm sure the answer is it need not have infinitely many zeros.

Comment: Hi @MattSamuel, cosh($\sqrt{z}$) is entire -- would you agree?  Looking at its exponential formula, any jump in the argument at the branch cut is offset by the jump in the argument at the (same) branch cut of the -$\sqrt{z}$ term, resulting in a net effect of 0 argument jump, so the multi-valuedness is canceled out, I believe.  And regarding such f(z)'s with the above growth rate not having infinitely many zeros, wouldn't that suggest f(z) then has polynomial growth, a contradiction?  Thanks,

Comment: This is trivial if (and, I believe, only if) you are familiar with the Hadamard factorization.

Comment: $\cosh(\sqrt z)$ is entire and has infinitely many zeros. And like you said, if it has no zeros then there's no contradiction,  such as for $e^z$, which doesn't have the same growth rate. I may be missing something, I haven't actually found a function myself, maybe there isn't one and I'm wrong.

Comment: If F(z) is a polynomial of positive degree then F(1/z) has a pole at 0. If F(z) is analytic and not a polynomial then F(1/z) has an essential singularity at 0.

Comment: Hi @user254665, by Liouville's theorem if F(z) were bounded and entire, then it is constant.  So I agree that a positive-degree, non-constant polynomial must grow to infinity.  However, how do we know that the singularity at infinity (for a polynomial) cannot be essential, and that it is at most a pole (of order n)?  Is it a Big Picard argument?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @ChristianRemling, I am not, actually.  So it's probably a great time to read up on it now.  Thanks so much for the hint :-)

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks as usual for your quick responses @MattSamuel :-)

Comment: No problem. {}{}{}{}{}{}{}

Comment: When f(z) is a non-constant polynomial , |f(z)| gores to infinity uniformly as |z| does, so by big Picard, on the Riemann sphere f does not have an essential singularity at infinity.